# How can I turn off AWS CLI(2) dynamodb responses requiring me to press Q on the keyboard? (aka silent)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I've read through AWS CLI documentation and I can't find a way to turn of the requirement of pressing a key.

E.g. If I run this command I am forced to press Q to exit the response.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region x
```

I'm writing scripts to build and populate tables and then tear them down but I have to press Q between every command.

Comment: You can also add `--no-cli-pager` when running the awscli.

Comment: Or set `AWS_PAGER=""` in your shell startup script. Also, this [seems](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5343) to be an unpopular default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS CLI v2 introduced a default pager.

The easiest way to deactivate it is to put this in the `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

For more options, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)